# Render text from decorator in Aurelia

Tags: html, typescript, aurelia

I'm dynamically building a form from a model:

```
export class Link {
    @required
    text: string = "";
    @required
    url: string = "";
}
```

I'd like to be able add a description in a decorator and render it, something like this:

```
export class Link {
    @required
    @description('This is the text that will display in the browser')
    text: string = "";
    @required
    url: string = "";
}
```

Anybody know how to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

The use case for this is to be able to display in a dynamically built form:

```
<form if.bind="editMode === 2" role="form" validation-renderer="validation-renderer">
    <div class="labeled-field form-group" repeat.for="key of editSetting.data | objectKeys">
        <span class="label">${key | camelCaseToWords}</span>
        <input class="input" type="text" value.bind="editSetting.data[key] & validate" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is it that you want to put the text in a decorator? What is your use case?

Comment: @HectorRomeroGranillo - I've added a use case in the original post